# How to set up a Github Actions strategy when cross compiling golang to use a specific binary suffix?

Tags: go, github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow that builds several binaries:

```
back:
(...)
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [linux, windows]
        arch: [amd64]
    steps:
(...)
      - run: env GOOS=${{matrix.os}} GOARCH=${{matrix.arch}} go build
```

This will create the files `mybinary` and `mybinary.exe`. There is however a problem when I have more architectures because the naming will collide.

A solution I had in mind is to use

```
env GOOS=${{matrix.os}} GOARCH=${{matrix.arch}} go build -o ${{matrix.os}}-${{matrix.arch}}-mybinary
```

Unfortunately this means that the Windows executable will not have the expected `.exe` suffix.

Is there a way to tell Actions to

```
env GOOS=${{matrix.os}} GOARCH=${{matrix.arch}} go build -o ${{matrix.os}}-${{matrix.arch}}-mybinary[.exe if ${{matrix.os}} == 'windows']
```

Comment: Why not rename them afterward? `for x in windows*; do mv $x $x.exe; done`

Comment: @Peter: excellent idea! Can you please convert that into an answer, I guess there is no built-in solution so that one will be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Github Actions support conditionals, but you can just rename the binaries after building them:

```
for x in windows-*; do mv $x $x.exe; done
```